# setting script path in a buildout using one of the distutils recipes

Tags: python, distutils, buildout

I am using buildout.  I am using it to install openerp.  I would like the scripts that openerp  creates to run itself available in ${buildout:location}/bin

I tried [zerokspot.recipe.distutils](http://github.com/zerok/zerokspot.recipe.distutils/)  and [collective.recipe.distutils](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.recipe.distutils/0.1)

How would I get the scripts built in bin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some help and  some research, it seems that openerp is hardly a standard distutils package.  After some research and some help, I tracked down

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cns.recipe.symlink/0.1

Which I shall use to link the executables to the buildout.  This will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Did you successfuly installed openerp with buildout ?

On my side it just cannot find these modules, but they are in my eggs dir:

```
Error: python module psycopg2 (PostgreSQL module) is required
Error: python module libxslt (libxslt python bindings) is required
Error: python module pychart (pychart module) is required
Error: python module pydot (pydot module) is required
error: Setup script exited with 1
An error occured when trying to install openerp-server 5.0.0-3. Look above this message for any errors that were output by easy_install.
```

Is this possible that openerp hardcoded the his searching path somewhere ?

My buildout.cfg look like this:

```
[buildout]
parts = eggs
versions=versions
newest = false
extensions = lovely.buildouthttp
unzip = true
find-links =
       http://download.gna.org/pychart/
[versions]

[eggs]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
interpreter = python
eggs =
     Paste
     PasteScript
     PasteDeploy
     psycopg2
     PyChart
     pydot
     openerp-server
```

Comment: I think you need to ask this as a top level question.